# is it possible to avoid code duplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If find an invite, the user must not specify email. I did so, right?

is it possible to avoid code duplication?

```
<% if @invitation %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.placeholder.email'), value: @invitation.email %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.placeholder.email') %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without the conditional like so:

```
f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.placeholder.email'), value: @invitation && @invitation.email, autofocus: !@invitation
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hard to read, but you can merge your options:

```
<% f.email_field(:email, {class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.placeholder.email')}.merge(@invitation ? {value: @invitation.email} : {autofocus: true})) %>
```